# AWS S3: bucketpolicy grants a level of public access that conflicts with your Block Public Access settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I have a bucket which has *Block all public access* turned to on. I am trying to apply a bucket policy like below

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1702547312345",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1702547293870",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::samples3-900-sample/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "10.0.0.0/8",
                        "40.0.0.0/8",
                        "146.111.111.0/23"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but I get error `You either don’t have permissions to edit the bucket policy, or your bucket policy grants a level of public access that conflicts with your Block Public Access settings.`

But since I am infra admin, its not a problem of missing permission. When I remove the `10`. & `40`. subnet it works  or removing  `146.` & retaining `10.` and `40.`  subnet works successfully. Why is it that I cannot combine all together?

Comment: `10.0.0.0/8` is a private CIDR and `aws:SourceIp` works only for public ranges https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access-analyzer-reference-policy-checks.html#access-analyzer-reference-policy-checks-error-private-ip-address

Comment: If that is the case, how in the above example, even if i remove the 146.111.111.0/23 range, it gets added successfully?